# Better way to forward fill nil values in clojure list

Tags: clojure

I wrote a function to forward fill nil values in a given list. The function works as expected, but I was wondering if there is a better (read more idiomatic) way of achieving this in clojure.

By forward fill nil values I mean: propagate the last non-nil element forward to next non-nil element.

**Function**

```
(defn ffill [mylist first-value last-value]
  (let [mylist-0 (concat (list first-value) mylist)
        mylist-N (concat mylist-0 (list (dec (count mylist-0))))
        mylist-idx (map-indexed (fn [i val] (if (not (nil? val)) i nil)) mylist-N)
        mylist-idx-no-nils (filter #(->> % (nil?) (not)) mylist-idx)
        ffidx (flatten (map #(repeat (- %2 %1) %1) mylist-idx-no-nils (next mylist-idx-no-nils)))]
    (map #(nth mylist-N %) (next ffidx))
     ))
```

**Examples**

```
(ffill '(nil nil nil "a" "b" "c" nil "d" nil) "a" "d")
("a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "c" "c" "d" "d")

(ffill '("z" nil nil "a" "b" "c" nil "d" nil) "a" "d")
("z" "z" "z" "a" "b" "c" "c" "d" "d")

(ffill '("z" nil nil "a" "b" "c" nil "e") "a" "d")
("z" "z" "z" "a" "b" "c" "c" "e")

(ffill '(0 nil nil nil 4 5 nil nil 8 nil) 0 8)
(0 0 0 0 4 5 5 5 8 8)

(ffill '(0 nil nil nil 4 5 nil nil 8) 0 8)
(0 0 0 0 4 5 5 5 8)

(ffill '(nil nil nil nil 4 5 nil nil 8 nil) 0 8)
(0 0 0 0 4 5 5 5 8 8)
```

Comment: Can you clearly specify what your function is supposed to do? Forwarding nil values is pretty vage.

Comment: Sure, I edited the question. I hope this is clearer now: "By forward fill nil values I mean: propagate the last non-nil element forward to next non-nil element."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `lazy-seq`:

```
(defn left-fill-lazy [init coll]
  (when (seq coll)
    (lazy-seq
      (let [v (first coll)
            n (if (some? v) v init)]
        (cons n (left-fill-lazy n (rest coll)))))))

(left-fill-lazy "a" '(nil nil "a" nil "c" nil "d" nil))
=> ("a" "a" "a" "a" "c" "c" "d" "d")
```

You could use a transducer that tracks the most recent non-nil value:

```
(defn left-fill
  ([] (left-fill nil))
  ([init]
   (fn [rf]
     (let [p (volatile! init)]
       (fn
         ([] (rf))
         ([result] (rf result))
         ([result input]
          (if (some? input)
            (do (vreset! p input)
                (rf result input))
            (rf result @p))))))))

(sequence (left-fill "a") '(nil nil "a" nil "c" nil "d" nil))
=> ("a" "a" "a" "a" "c" "c" "d" "d")
```

You could (ab)use zippers for the same effect:

```
(defn left-fill-zip [l]
  (loop [loc (z/seq-zip l)]
    (if (z/end? loc)
      (z/root loc)
      (recur
        (z/next
          (cond
            (some? (z/node loc)) loc
            (z/left loc) (z/replace loc (z/node (z/left loc)))
            :else loc))))))

(left-fill-zip '("z" nil nil ("a" "b" ("c" nil) "d" nil)))
=> ("z" "z" "z" ("a" "b" ("c" "c") "d" "d"))
```

Answer (score 3):

From what i can see, the last parameter of your function is unused. Given that, the following should work. If I misunderstood something regarding the parameter, please let me know.

```clj
(defn propagate-non-nil-values [s begin]
  (when (seq s)
    (if (nil? (first s))
      (cons begin (propagate-non-nil-values (rest s) begin))
      (cons (first s) (propagate-non-nil-values (rest s) (first s))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `reductions`:

```clj
(defn fwd-fill [x xs]
 (rest
   (reductions 
     (fn [a x] (or x a))
     x
     xs)))  

(fwd-fill 0 '(nil nil nil nil 4 5 nil nil 8 nil))
;==> (0 0 0 0 4 5 5 5 8 8)
```

Comment: I'm rusty, but I think you could just do `(rest (reductions (fn [a x] (if (nil? x) a x)) default xs))` where `default` is the value to replace any initial `nil`s. Saves you from creating a pair just to map the first back out.

Comment: Updated base on @A. Webb suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version, similar to others above:

```clj
(defn ffill [xs default]
  (when (seq xs)
    (let [x           (first xs)
          new-default (if (nil? x) default x)]
      (cons new-default
            (lazy-seq (ffill (rest xs) new-default))))))

;; (ffill '(nil nil nil "a" "b" "c" nil "d" nil) "a")
;; => ("a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "c" "c" "d" "d")

;; (ffill '("z" nil nil "a" "b" "c" nil "d" nil) "a")
;; => ("z" "z" "z" "a" "b" "c" "c" "d" "d")

;; (ffill '("z" nil nil "a" "b" "c" nil "e") "a")
;; => ("z" "z" "z" "a" "b" "c" "c" "e")

;; (ffill '(0 nil nil nil 4 5 nil nil 8 nil) 0)
;; => (0 0 0 0 4 5 5 5 8 8)

;; (ffill '(0 nil nil nil 4 5 nil nil 8) 0)
;; => (0 0 0 0 4 5 5 5 8)

;; (ffill '(nil nil nil nil 4 5 nil nil 8 nil) 0)
;; => (0 0 0 0 4 5 5 5 8 8)

;; (ffill '(nil true nil false nil) 1)
;; => (1 true true false false)
```

- `when` takes care of the end of the sequence of `xs`
- `new-default` is determined to be the head of the current portion of the list or the provided default for this iteration
- `lazy-seq` because the list doesn't need to be finite

EDIT: My previous solution used `or`, which was incorrect since it would replace `false` values as if they were `nil`, so I updated my answer.